# Play Rdio.com song streaming

Tags: ios, rdio

I'm trying to implement online music search and sample streaming features for an iOS app: the user may be able to search music by song name/artist/album and reproduce them. I found Rdio.com looks promising, however, can't figure out a way to solve this.

The streaming API expects a key, such as

`[rdio.player playSource:@"t2742133"];`

but I'm having difficulties to trace how can I get the key `"t2742133"` for a given song, as it seems there's no documented method for getting a song metadata based on its name. Anyone experienced with Rdio.com could tell if there's a (relatively) straight forward way to get a song info by its name, and which would be the main steps to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a direct method for the iOS sdk, but for searching purposes there's a REST api instead.-

http://developer.rdio.com/docs/REST/

The responses include track ids that can be passed to iOS api streaming method.